# Adding ports to existing kubernetes service

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, kubernetes

I have a service in kubernetes that is exposed on port 80 via load balancer on AWS.
I also have a DNS configured to point on the load balancer host name.

I want to add another port to the service without replacing it, which also replaces the load balancer and its domain.

The only option I saw is to apply "patch" operation via kubectl.
Is there a more convenient way I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with ELB, so I don't know if it is possible, but I'll talk about GCE and then assert that AWS should operate similarly.

In Kubernetes v1.0.x there is an unfortunate bug that releases your external load-balancer and recreates it when you update a Service.  In Kubernetes v1.1 we have gone to great lengths to NOT release the load-balancer (more precisely the external IP), so that a PUT or a PATCH (kubectl replace or kubectl patch) on the Service is safe.  If AWS releases the external load-balancer (I know it's not an IP for ELB) then we should try to find a way to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AWS won't release an ELB on its own, it must be given with an explicit command to do so. On version 1.0.x it looks like the service is dropped and created again, which means the ELBs are replaced. If on version 1.1.x you don't drop the service (meaning the ELB drops) then things should work as expected. I think it is very crucial for service stablity.

Comment: Just another note: If we don't drop the ELB we must alter it to fit the new service port requirements. ELBs works with listeners so if for example I have an nginx listening on port 80 and exposed as a load-balancer service in kubernetes then the ELB has a listener on port 80 which forwards the traffic to kubernetes minions on the designated node port of the service. If now I add a port 443 to the nginx service, we have to create another listener on the exisiting ELB.

Comment: Should I open it as an issue in kubernetes github?

Comment: If it is actually dropping the ELB to do the updates, then yes, please open a GitHub issue